# How to obtain info about physical volume as non root user

Tags: linux, lvm

Hello the pvs command gives me the following output:

```
 PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
 /dev/sd**  ***** lvm2 a-   59.49g 47.49g
 /dev/sd**  ***** lvm2 a-   25.00g  8.00m
```

This only works if I am root user.

Can a different command be used to get this info as a non-root user.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pvs` command, but maybe `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or even `df` command might help you.

Comment: Probably not. Have you considered using `sudo`?

Comment: I used sudo /sbin/pvs, but the non root user had root priviliges, i'm looking for a way that any user can get disk info

Answer (score 10):

Any user can get information with `lsblk`. 
It has options that allow you to get simple output,
full detailed or customized.

Try:

- **`lsblk`**

  ```
  $ lsblk

  NAME                            MAJ:MIN  RM    SIZE  RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
  sda                               8:0     0  238,5G   0  disk
  ├─sda1                            8:1     0      2M   0  part
  ├─sda2                            8:2     0    700M   0  part  /boot
  └─sda3                            8:3     0  206,4G   0  part
    ├─fed21_ssd_pcsolo-swap       253:0     0   29,8G   0  lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─fed21_ssd_pcsolo-root       253:1     0     80G   0  lvm   /
    ├─fed21_ssd_pcsolo-home       253:2     0     50G   0  lvm   /home
    └─fed21_ssd_pcsolo-tmp        253:3     0   46,6G   0  lvm   /tmp
  sdb                               8:16    0    2,7T   0  disk
             ⋮
  ```
- **`lsblk -f`**  (Output info about filesystems)
- **`lsblk -b`**  (Print the SIZE column in bytes rather than in a human-readable format) or **`lsblk -m`** (Output info about device owner, group and mode)
- **`lsblk -O`** (capital "o") this is full detailed
- **`lsblk -o`** (Specify which output columns to print) you can define custom format

Comment: Yeah but this doesn't show the LVM stats, like cache hits

Answer (score 4):

The `pvs` command is part of `lvm`. If you, as root, need to enable non-root users this funtionality, you can use `setcap`, to set the lvm executable permissions to perform actions that are restricted to root by default.
This goes to any executable that needs to do root-privileged actions.

Read more about the file capabilities: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

An example:  BEFORE `setcap`

```
 $ pvs
 WARNING: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable.
 /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: Permission denied
 WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad: Permission denied. Falling back to internal     scanning.
 /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: Permission denied
 /run/lock/lvm/P_global:aux: open failed: Permission denied
 Unable to obtain global lock.
```

AFTER

```
setcap "cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_resource,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap=+eip" /sbin/lvm 

$ pvs
WARNING: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable.
PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/sda2  centos        lvm2 a--  15.51g    0
/dev/sdb   DataPool      lvm2 a--  50.00g    0
/dev/sdc   DataPool      lvm2 a--  60.00g    0
/dev/sdd   DBArchivePool lvm2 a--  50.00g    0
```

Notice that I used much more caps than needed, probably, because I just copied something that I used once, but you might find your minimal set of caps...

Don't forget to quote the caps you want to set.

Comment: I typed in command: `cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_admin,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_resource,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap=+eip" /sbin/lvm :` but i get `>` as error. What am I doing wrong? Can I run this command as non root user.

Comment: I edited my answer, so that the command will be clearer. And no, you can't run this command as a non-root user. I wrote that you have to be root to allow this access. After setting the caps, any non-root user should be able to run `pvs`

Comment: Actually I would think of this as a pretty dumb thing to do. For example this allows anyone on your system to modify logical volumes.